# Parameter not set in JPA Native Query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

i am developing a backend in Spring Boot, i am using JPA for all the DB operations. The problem is the following:

i receive a parameter named "responsableServicio" from the frontend, first it gets to the controller method where i checked the parameter gets there correctly. However, when the parameter goes from controller to repository, the value is not getting correctly, it seems being empty because my query should return 1 record and is returning 0 records.

i would like to highlight that if i put the parameter hardcoded in the query, it returns the correct result 1.

i followed some examples but is not working yet. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Formulario Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/getCountAnexos")
    @ResponseBody
    public String countAnexosRechazo(@RequestBody String responsableServicio) {
        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Cambiar a nativeQuery

        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println(responsableServicio);
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        String respuesta = formularioRepository.getAnexosRechazados(responsableServicio);
        System.out.printf("RESPUESTA",respuesta);

        return respuesta;
}
```

Formulario Repository

```
// Consulta para obtener el numero de Anexos Rechazados de acuerdo el Usuario
    @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM formulario where year(fechaTramite)='2020' and responsableServicio = :responsableServicio and (estatusGestorContratos = 'Rechazado' or estatusAFTI = 'Rechazado')", nativeQuery = true)
    public abstract String getAnexosRechazados(@Param("responsableServicio") String responsableServicio);
```

What i get from console

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrUwA.png)

Comment: can you try to hardcode the value in the controller?

Comment: @RyanGuamos already did it. Neither worked

Comment: try to modify your query using  the exact column name. not camelCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Controller Class. It is taking String as complete JSON with brackets.
Here you have taken a @PostMapping and using @RequestBody String responsableServicio as a method parameter. You cannot take String as a type parameter, you have to create a class having String responsableServicio as a variable with its getters/setters.
Then within controller take argument as a class paramater.

```
class RequestDTO{
    String responsableServicio;
    public String getResponsableServicio() {
        return responsableServicio;
    }
    public void setResponsableServicio(String responsableServicio) {
        this.responsableServicio = responsableServicio;
    }
}
```

Write controller as

```
@PostMapping(path = "/getCountAnexos")
@ResponseBody
public String countAnexosRechazo(@RequestBody RequestDTO responsableServicio) {
    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // Cambiar a nativeQuery

    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println(responsableServicio.getResponsableServicio());
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    String respuesta = formularioRepository.getAnexosRechazados(responsableServicio.getResponsableServicio());
    System.out.printf("RESPUESTA",respuesta);

    return respuesta;
}
```

That will work fine..!!

If that too not works then, 
1) Check the @Query you have imported should be from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`

2) Check the Repository interface has @Repository annotation.

3) Check the @Param is imported from `org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param`